# Typescript not enforcing that non-optional parameters / identifiers are provided to callback function argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm making a function in TS which provides the equivalent functionality of Array.prototype.map() for dictionaries (objects within which all of the values share the same type). The function itself works just fine:

```
// Array.prototype.map, but for Dict
function mapDict<T, M>(dict: Dict<T>, callback: (dictValue: T, dictKey: string, dict: Dict<T>) => M): Dict<M> {
  const mappedDict: Dict<M> = {}
  for (let keyValPair of Object.entries(dict)) {
    const mappedVal: M = callback(keyValPair[1], keyValPair[0], dict);
    mappedDict[keyValPair[0]] = mappedVal;
  }
  return mappedDict;
};
```

However, what I'm struggling to understand is the following. In the typed function declaration above, we explicitly say that the second argument mapDict should take is a callback function which takes three arguments (none of which are optional) and returns a type which is cast onto our second generic type M. Bearing that in mind, why does TS not complain when I do this:

```
const fruits = {
  apple: { color: "red", mass: 100 },
  grape: { color: "red", mass: 5 },
  banana: { color: "yellow", mass: 183 },
  lemon: { color: "yellow", mass: 80 },
  pear: { color: "green", mass: 178 },
  orange: { color: "orange", mass: 262 },
  raspberry: { color: "red", mass: 4 },
  cherry: { color: "red", mass: 5 },
}
 
interface Dict<T> {
  [k: string]: T
}


const mappedDict = mapDict(fruits, (fruit) => {
  // return {
  //   ...fruit,
  //   kg: 0.001 * fruit.mass
  // }
});
```

As you can see, in the above invocation of mapDict, the callback I've passed in as an argument only has one argument / identifier, whereas I've explicitly stated it must receive three, and yet TS is totally fine with it. If I had to make a guess as to what's going on here, I would say that TS what is actually enforcing is how many arguments are passed into the callback when the callback is *invoked*, and in the code above, the callback is always invoked with three arguments which adheres to the way we typed it. While that does somewhat make sense, it still confuses me that we explicitly tell TS "this argument must be a function that takes receives three arguments / identifiers", and yet there are no complaints if we provide a function that only takes one.

Could somebody explain more clearly the behaviour that's occurring here?

Comment: The same applies to the usage of `Array.prototype.map`. The callback is typed as `callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void` but you get no error if you only use the `value` like `[0].map(v => {})`. Imagine how annoying it would be to be forced to also define `i` and `array` if you don't use them.

Comment: Indeed, I'm aware that the same behaviour applies with `Array.prototype.map`, and I know that my code is behaving the way it should, in that it would be a waste of time to demand that programmers declare identifiers for parameters they'll never end up using within their callback function, just like you said. What I don't get though is why the second and third parameters don't have to be declared as optional by appending a `?` to them, in order for TS to not complain when they're not provided, as in my example.